# Python: How to create separate arrays for each line in the text

Tags: python, arrays

I have a text file which has an array for each line. As shown below, what I want to have is a separate array for each line. For example:

```
a1 =[35.947, -54.045, 75.418]    
a2=[36.467, -53.041, 74.451]
```

---

```
[35.947, -54.045, 75.418]
[36.467, -53.041, 74.451]
[35.359, -52.008, 74.353]
```

This is how far I can get:

```
 def readFile(self):
    with open(self.file) as file:
        list = [line.strip() for line in open(self.file)]
    for i in range(len(list)):
```

Comment: Storing arrays/lists in a `.txt` is  not a good idea, Python has a nice module named `Pickle`

Comment: I wouldn't prefer it too. But gotta find out how ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create dictionary to store a mapping of variable names and their values, In the dictionary the keys are the variable names stored as strings, and the value is a list of `float` values.

```
variable_dict = {}

with open("sample.txt", "r") as data_file:
    for line in data_file.readlines():
        var_name, value = line.strip().replace(" ", "").split("=")
        variable_dict[var_name] = map(float,value[1:-1].split(","))

print variable_dict
>>> {'a1': [35.947, -54.045, 75.418], 'a2': [36.467, -53.041, 74.451]}

print variable_dict["a1"]    #Accessing some varibale 
>>> [35.947, -54.045, 75.418]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been trying to figure out. Thanks for the help anmol_uppal.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is read simple expressions from plain text files.
Eg:
If the file contains

```
a1 = [35.947, -54.045, 75.418]
[36.467, -53.041, 74.451]
[35.359, -52.008, 74.353]
```

Then using `eval()` on lines 2 and 3 might give you something like

```
>> type(data[1])
str

>> data[1]
'[36.467, -53.041, 74.451]\n'

>> a = eval(data[1])

>> a
[36.467, -53.041, 74.451]

>> type(a)
list
```

But eval() on line 1 is going to fail since eval only parses expressions with known values. and a1 is not a known value. From my opinion thats the best you can do

Comment: Line 1 (in your case) is what I want from line 1 from the text actually. So if line 1 in text file is [36.467, -53.041, 74.451] then for each line of the text I should create an array. And each array should have 3 values.

Comment: `eval` will help you get the array(list in python) from your text